# How to make a staircase / step line using svg in reactjs / nextjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, next.js13, clip-path

Hey guys i am very new to svg path animations,
i am trying to re create steps / stair svg path something like below
[image]

How do i proceed to make something like this ?
animated as in on scroll it fix color of the line?

const ZigZagLine = () => {
return (








);
};

```
<div>
  <div>Div one</div>
  <div>Div two</div>
</div>
```